# MongoDB: how to assign index names to the elements of an array in the aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here is an array which I got after a long aggregation.

```
  "stages": [
     [
        {
           "id": "58a6678bc27c331884b60930",
           "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
           "somevalue": 0,
           "user": "589cf6511b94281f34617a13"
        },
        {
           "_id": "589cf6511b94281f34617a13",
           "title": "Dr.",
           "firstname": "Doe",
           "lastname": "John"
        }
     ]
  ]
```

As you see, now I have a heap of arrays nested in each other. Is there a way to either unify the two sets within the array or give them proper index names?

Possible solution #1 would be this. The inner array is gone and the sets are united.

```
  "stages": [
        {
           "id": "58a6678bc27c331884b60930",
           "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
           "somevalue": 0,
           "user": "589cf6511b94281f34617a13"
           "_id": "589cf6511b94281f34617a13",
           "title": "Dr.",
           "firstname": "Doe",
           "lastname": "John"
        }
  ]
```

Possible solution #2: the array not gone, but at least the elements now have index names and I don't have to refer to them as [0] and [1].

```
  "stages": [
     [
        "stage": {
           "id": "58a6678bc27c331884b60930",
           "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
           "somevalue": 0,
           "user": "589cf6511b94281f34617a13"
        },

        "user": {
           "_id": "589cf6511b94281f34617a13",
           "title": "Dr.",
           "firstname": "Doe",
           "lastname": "John"
        }
     ]
  ]
```

A virtual cookie to anyone with a solution...

Aggregation Code

```
db.collection('bugs').aggregate([{
                $match: new ObjectId()
            }, {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'users',
                    localField: 'user',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'userdata'
                }
            },

            {
                $unwind: '$userdata'
            },

            {
                $sort: {
                    'stages.date': -1
                }
            },

            {
                $unwind: '$stages'
            }, {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'users',
                    localField: 'stages.user',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'stages_users'
                }
            },

            {
                $unwind: '$stages_users'
            }, {
                $unwind: '$stages'
            },

            {
                $group: {
                    '_id': '$_id',
                    'title': {
                        $first: '$title'
                    },
                    'user': {
                        $first: '$user'
                    },
                    'browser': {
                        $first: '$browser'
                    },
                    'severity': {
                        $first: '$severity'
                    },
                    'data': {
                        $first: '$data'
                    },
                    'userdata': {
                        $first: '$userdata'
                    },
                    'stages': {
                        $addToSet: {
                            $setUnion: [
                                ['$stages_users'],
                                ['$stages']
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            {
                $project: {

                    '_id': 1,
                    'user': 1,
                    'title': 1,
                    'browser': 1,
                    'date': 1,
                    'severity': 1,

                    'userdata._id': 1,
                    'userdata.title': 1,
                    'userdata.firstname': 1,
                    'userdata.lastname': 1,

                    'stages._id': 1,
                    'stages.id': 1,
                    'stages.user': 1,
                    'stages.date': 1,
                    'stages.description': 1,
                    'stages.severity': 1,
                    'stages.previous_severity': 1,
                    'stages.files': 1,

                    'stages.title': 1,
                    'stages.firstname': 1,
                    'stages.lastname': 1
                }
            }
        ],
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to post the aggregation code ? May be it is easier to add names before your final output.

Comment: Yes, but you may spend the weekend figuring it out...
http://pastebin.com/SNPuZWG0

It is a simple ticket system for a bug reporting module. The bug report has a header in the collection named "bugs" which contains date, title and _id of user who posted it. Follow-ups are called stages and are stored in an array named "stages" for every record of "bugs". The stages also have "user" fields, for the person who posted them, and the aggregation is supposed to look up these users and add them to the "stages" array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation.

So the idea here is to merge the fields from `stages` and `stage_users` into `stages_merge_users` document after `$lookup` in the `$project` stage.

I have added field each from `stages` and `stage_users` for demonstration.

You have to add all the fields one at a time from both the documents and the final stage is to `$group` stages back together.

```
db.bugs.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'users',
        localField: 'user',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'userdata'
    }
}, {
    $unwind: '$stages'
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'users',
        localField: 'stages.user',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'stages_users'
    }
}, {
    $unwind: '$stages_users'
}, {
    $project: {
        '_id': 1,
        'user': 1,
        'title': 1,
        'browser': 1,
        'date': 1,
        'severity': 1,
        'userdata': 1,
        "stages_merge_users.firstname": "$stages_users.firstname",
        "stages_merge_users.user": "$stages.user"
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        '_id': '$_id',
        'title': {
            $first: '$title'
        },
        'user': {
            $first: '$user'
        },
        'browser': {
            $first: '$browser'
        },
        'severity': {
            $first: '$severity'
        },
        'data': {
            $first: '$data'
        },
        'userdata': {
            $first: '$userdata'
        },
        'stages': {
            $push: '$stages_merge_users'

        }
    }
}])
```

Version 3.4 Update

You can replace the `$project` stage with `$addFields`. This stages add fields to the existing fields.

```
{$addFields: {  "stages_merge_users.firstname":"$stages_users.firstname", "stages_merge_users.user_id":"$stages.user_id"}},
```

Comment: Oh, so I can use $project before other operations! That's cool, I thought that's the end of it. However this whole thing seems a lot more complicated than in SQL. Thanks for the solution. I'd appreciate a 3.4 solution too.

Comment: You are welcome. Added the 3.4 update. I mean the `$lookup` & `$group` stage is still the same when compared to sql. The rest is pretty standard. You can use aggregation stages in any order you want.